# Delete/move file during exec: in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, exec

i have this scenario: a folder is a drop-target for some xml and pdf-files. When files are detected, an exec (windows cmd-file) is initiated, which processes the files in this folder and moves them elsewhere. Works - almost.

The problem is, that one of the files stays locked while the exec-target is active. It can't be moved and stays around until the next cycle two hours later.

The lock is released when the exec is finished.
I understand that locking the file may help in transactional processing, but somehow it should be possible to say 'thanks for delivering the file(s) to this place, but now keep your fingers off before calling an external command-file.
I started with Camel 2.19.3 and changed to 2.20.0 yesterday.

The route is simply this:

```
   public void configure() throws Exception {

        from( recvFolderName + "?include=.*\\.(pdf|xml)"
                +   "&delay=5000"
               // +   "&idempotent=true"
                +   "&noop=true"
                +   "&readLock=none"
                +   "")
                .log("before processing downloaded file: ${file:name}")
                .process( new MyTestProcessor() )
                .onException( FileNotFoundException.class ).handled( true ).end()
                .onException( GenericFileOperationFailedException.class ).handled( true ).end()                
                .to( "exec:" + extShellScript
                + "?workingDir=c:/Sahara/emcs/"
                + "&outFile=c:/Sahara/LogFile.txt"
                + "&useStderrOnEmptyStdout=true"
                )             
                .log("after processing downloaded file: ${file:name}")
```

Comment: Is this folder being used by a lot of processes? Or only the commandlet process? The locking is recommended when you have multiple processes reading from the folder.

Comment: no - the folder is only used to drop incoming files from another route - SFTP. I have the impression that the readLock in the from-clause is to watch for a lock on the _incoming_ file, and not to hold a lock towards the to-clause. When MyTestProcessor is active, there is no lock. It is set only during the exec-part.

Comment: Whom is doing the file locking exactly? Also mind that if you run an exec script then that script may cause a file locking as well.

Comment: Also if its small files (not GBs or big MBs in size) you can try to convert the message into String or byte[] before calling exec then its not a FileInputStream that the exec is being given (which can cause a lock until the stream is closed). And also what OS are you using? Windows, linux etc.

Comment: the locking is done by camel. The windows test-batchfile (a .cmd-file) just moves the files away - and it calls Sysinternals handle-command to show locked files. The real batchfile would call another program to do some processing with the files, before moving them away. I am considering to add a dummy file during the sftp-download which would trigger this route, catch the lock and the real files would pass through without lock. I am also considering to break down the processing inside the real batchfile to have everything handled by camel - but i somehow expect to find the file locked...